# What to look for in bad pg_dump log

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, dump, pg-dump

We want to programmatically detect errors in cron scheduled pg_dumps.

Apart from cheking whether or not the log file ends in "pg_dump: saving database definition":

What other tell-tale string can I grep for in order to programatically check a dump is ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main indicator is the exit status of the `pg_dump` command. If it's non-zero, then something went wrong otherwise it worked all along. This is the implicit contract between any command and the shell, and breaching it would be a bug.
And it's also testable when the sub-command could't be launched at all.

Here's a basic skeleton in Unix shell that tests the exit code and acts accordingly:

```
d=`date +%Y%m%d`
dump=/path/to/backups/daily-backup-"$d"
error=/path/to/backups/errors-backup-"$d".txt

pg_dump -U username dbname >$dump 2>$error
code=$?
if [ $code -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "The backup failed (exit code $code), check for errors in $error"
fi
```

It is necessary to keep the error messages in durable storage so that they can be analyzed later.
When no error at all occurs, the file for errors should be there but empty, unless the `-v` option is used but it's intentionally not in the above script.

About the message: *saving database definition*

It is displayed along with lots of other informational messages only when using the verbose (`-v`) option. The problem is that in case of error, these messages will be mixed with error messages, and it requires some level of expertise to distinguish what's normal from what's not.

Comment: Would this: `$pg_dump $BACKUP_OPTIONS --file $BACKUP_FILE $DATABASE >> $BACKUP_FILE.log 2>&1` do the same as this: `pg_dump -U username dbname >$dump 2>$error`  ? If not, please explain. I have doubts about the `2>&1` part vs `2>$error`.

Comment: @user1598390: I believe it's the same in practice. But strictly speaking, when `--file` is used, the standard output channel is free for whatever message `pg_dump` **could** decide to output, so I wouldn't be too confident about it. In backup scripts especially, better safe than sorry.

Comment: I didn't understand *"the standard output channel is free for whatever message pg_dump could decide to output"*.

Comment: With `pg_dump >file.dump` the standard output is dedicated to the dump file. With `pg_dump --file file.dump`, it's not, so if it wanted, the program could print some messages to the standard output in addition to dumping the database into the file.

Comment: The problem is that I need to check for errors in the dump **asyncronously**. That's why I need to check a logfile. It's the only why to check for errors off-line.

Answer (score -1):

Some programs don't behave nicely when used in a pipe on unix-like systems. For example, I was using pg_dump piped through gzip like so:

Broken script: error condition never occurs

```
export PGPASSWORD=secret
pg_dump -h host -U user db | gzip - > backup.sql.gz

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ### Never happens: gzip never fails! ###
    echo Backup failed.
    exit 1
fi
```

This uses the normal way of checking the exit status of the previous command ($?), but it doesn't work. If the pg_dump fails for any reason, gzip doesn't return any error response. $? is set to 0, indicating success.

Fortunately, there's a better way. In bash, the [PIPESTATUS](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#IDX213) environment variable is an array with the return codes of all the commands executed in the last pipe. Checking for the overall return status and the status of pg_dump is now done like this:

Correct script: check the result of pg_dump separately

```
export PGPASSWORD=secret
pg_dump -h host -U user db | gzip - > backup.sql.gz

if [ $? -ne 0 -o ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo Backup failed.
    exit 1
fi
```

Now I can be sure my automated database backups aren't going to fail silently.

From https://mattryall.net/blog/piped-exit-status

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, Im improved my answer.